# How to limit mdfind search depth

Tags: terminal, spotlight

I'm trying to run this query on my `~` folder `mdfind -onlyin . 'kMDItemDateAdded < $time.today'` but I want to limit the search depth to `~`. Is it possible?
I know this is best achieved with `find` but since I'm looking into searching by date attributes such as `kMDItemDateAdded` I don't think this can be achieved with `find`.

Comment: Does `mdls -attr kMDItemDateAdded` differ from the creation date of the file (which you can check for within `find`)?

Comment: Editors:  Please do not roll back or edit further.  The author’s own edits are perfectly fine  both in content and format.

Comment: @Allan Thought Alper's edit was better but alright.

Comment: You mean you want to limit a search of ~/ to not include subfolders?

Comment: @Allan: I am not sure what's going on lately with SE but every time I go away for a few days and come back to my question, I don't even remember what I was asking because of how much edited my question ended up. Editing only for the points and the 'presence' does nothing but harm the community, unfortunately.

Comment: @benwiggy: Yessir.

Comment: @nohillside: Hi again! Yes, it does differ by a long stretch.

Comment: @mariano-daniel - I agree. There has been some overzealous editing of late - the most egregious being rewording/rewriting to fit a personal style.    My "[edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/revisions/461152/5)" was to rollback all subsequent edits from your most recent submission. My thinking is the *original* author takes precedence.   I believe the mods have addressed it

Comment: This might be a good topic to post on [Meta]

Comment: As far as I can see, this is your only question with a somehow unhelpful edit history. But you always have the last say in edits and are free to rollback if you don't agree. If things get out of hand, please flag for mod attention before engaging in any discussion with over-eager editors.